# How can I deal with depressed Windows logo key when using `SendInput`?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

My application synthesises keystrokes in other apps by using `SendInput`. This almost works, except that due to circumstances I cannot change, the left Windows key will always be physically depressed when sending the input. This means that if, for example, the keystroke being sent is the 'd' key, then Windows sees the keystroke as its Win+D shortcut and displays the Desktop, and the 'd' keystroke never makes it to its intended target.

The documentation mentions this problem but is frustratingly vague about how to fix it (emphasis mine):

> This function does not reset the keyboard's current state. Any keys that are already pressed when the function is called might interfere with the events that this function generates. To avoid this problem, check the keyboard's state with the `GetAsyncKeyState` function and **correct as necessary**.

How should I "correct as necessary"?

I've tried using `SetKeyboardState` to turn off the keyboard state of the `VK_LWIN` key, after first attaching my thread to the thread of the window that I am sending the keystrokes to (with `AttachThreadInput`), but this doesn't seem to affect the behaviour at all.

I've also tried inserting a `KEYEVENTF_KEYUP` event at the start of the input I am sending with `SendInput`, but this causes the Start Menu to pop up and grab focus, which is obviously not acceptable.

What is the correct method of dealing with a depressed Windows logo key when calling SendInput?

**EDIT:**

As per [@Brian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914989/how-can-i-deal-with-depressed-windows-logo-key-when-using-sendinput/2915406#2915406) I can prevent the win key from interfering with my code by installing a low-level keyhook which traps win-key keydown events.

This, however, has the undesired effect that the Windows key is now disabled entirely. I can sort of envisage some solution to this where I keep a note of the state of all the keys within my keyhook, and simulate presses of the windows key when other keys are pressed, depending on whether or not they are the ones I'm simulating, but that sounds like a hack to me. Alternatively, I could use my keyhook to emulate important windows keyboard shortcuts.

But the documentation implies it should all work in a much more straightforward way. Brian's solution is to prevent the win key from getting to the pressed down state in the first place. But the documentation states that you should be able to check if it's pressed down later on, and correct it if it is.

Is it actually possible to do this?

Comment: I like to take my depressed keys out for an ice cream, that usually makes them feel better.

Answer (score 3):

[I basically solved this exact problem yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906179/low-level-keyboard-hooks-sendinput-with-winkeyl-possible-workstation-lockout-i) :) My code is in C#, but it mostly consists of win32 API calls via p/invoke, so it should translate directly to C++.

The solution is to use a [Low-Level Keyboard Hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(VS.85).aspx) to intercept the initial Windows key KeyDown event (and tell the OS that you handled it so that it won't be passed to other Applications and/or the OS). Then, depending on OS, simulate the Windows key KeyUp event before your input. It sounds like you're half-way there, you just need to intercept the initial KeyDown.

My solution is targeted at Windows Vista and Windows 7, so if you're in XP or below, it's possible that you don't need to send the KeyUp. That's what I'll be testing soon, it may work in both; however, Vista and 7 intercept the windows key more aggressively than XP, hence my suspicions.

Comment: @Brian. Thanks. I'm developing on Windows 7. If I intercept the KeyDown with a low-level Keyboard Hook then my code works fine (without having to simulate a KeyUp). However, this means that the windows key is completely disabled, and ideally I'd like the Windows key's functionality to be unaffected. Also, the documentation states you should "correct as necessary" immediately before the call to SendInput. Do you think this is actually impossible to do?

Comment: You can intercept the Windows key only in the specific cases you need, and let it pass through otherwise. Then you retain the normal functionality. To let it pass through, end your handler proc with CallNextHookEx (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644974(v=VS.85).aspx)

Comment: @Brian, but when the Windows key is pressed, I don't know whether or not it's going to be one of the specific cases I need. I only find that out when I decide to call `SendInput`, which is after the Windows key has already been held down.

Comment: You have to track the state of the keys you care about through their KeyDown/KeyUp cycle. If you read my original answer, I was doing exactly this with the combination WinKey+L. WinKey still works with every other combination, and functions as expected is you press and release it without a combination (opens the Start menu). The only downside is that "WinKey down" messages are delayed, but then sent only after "WinKey up" is intercepted. Fortunately, "WinKey down" is not a very important event for most purposes.

Comment: But your requirements are different to mine. You're swapping the Win and Ctrl Keys. What happens if you hold down the actual Windows key and press D? In that instance you are capturing the Windows keypress and simulating a Ctrl+D event instead. I need *some* win key presses to act as normal, but *other* ones to be remapped. You are remapping *all* of them to Ctrl presses. (And vice versa) Or is there something about your original answer I'm missing?

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, btw. It's appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

"Correcting" the state of a modifier key by inserting a `KEYEVENTF_KEYUP` event may have side-effects, but they can be avoided by inserting additional events.

The Start menu is triggered when the Win key is pressed and released, **except** when there is an intervening key event or if it was pressed in combination with another modifier. So instead of inserting just *Win-up*, insert *Ctrl-down*, *Win-up*, *Ctrl-up*.

Aside from the Start menu, releasing modifier keys might have other side-effects:

- Releasing Alt can activate the active window's menu (even if it doesn't appear to have one).
- Releasing Alt or Shift can activate the Alt+Shift language hotkey.
- Releasing Ctrl or Shift can activate the Ctrl+Shift language hotkey.
- Releasing any modifier key can activate the Office hotkey (in Windows 1903 and later, pressing and releasing Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Win opens the Office app).

Inserting a key-down and key-up (or possibly just a key-up without a prior key-down) with almost any other virtual keycode first will generally prevent any of these hotkeys from activating. One can use an undefined or reserved keycode such as 0xE8, although there is still a risk that another program makes use of it.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm no longer in a position where I am able to test this solution, but it sounds like a promising workaround. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just had exactly the same problem and stumbled upon this post.  In my case, the "hot key" that I was capturing included <Ctrl><Shift>, which were still being held down by the user (me for testing) when I used **SendInput** to send my keystrokes to the target application.  Part of my **SendInput** sequence was a <DEL> key (VK_DELETE), which does not register a keystroke at all if modified by the <Ctrl> or <Shift> keys the user used to trigger the hot hey.

I found [@Lexikos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64607000/7516356) answer to be very helpful.  I got around the side-effects by:

1. Only responding to the keyboard message when my target window was the Foreground Window (using **GetForgroundWindow()** and checking the active window's title).  Otherwise, just let the message pass to the next hook.
2. Since I'm only responding to keystrokes to my target application (active window), consuming the keystrokes in the message queue and do not pass them on.
3. Inserting both a key down event (no **dwFlags** set) followed by a key up event (KEYEVENTF_KEYUP) to release the virtual key.

I did find a few snags of my own:

- I had to put KEYDOWN/KEYUP inputs for both the Left and Right Shift keys (VK_LSHIFT and VK_RSHIFT) to cover both cases.  Using just VK_SHIFT did not work for me.
- I had to put KEYDOWN/KEYUP inputs for both the Left and Right Ctrl keys (VK_LCONTROL and VK_RCONTROL) to cover both cases.  Again, using just VK_CONTROL did not work for me.
- The right <Ctrl> key is an extended key on the 101 Keyboard, so both the key down and key up inputs needed to have **dwFlags** set to KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY or it did not register and release the right <Ctrl> key.
- The KEYDOWN/KEYUP message to clear the modifier keys ***must*** be sent in the same INPUT array, otherwise modifier key messages will slip back into the message queue and activate them again.

@Lexikos suggestion of sending an inert keystroke before these modifier resets may be valid; my sequence sends some UNICODE characters first that are not affected by the modifiers and then I reset the modifier keys right before susceptible virtual key.  Here's a code snippet for resetting the <Ctrl><Shift> modifiers in my INPUT array:

```
// ^^^ Other keystrokes inserted above ^^^

// Issue KEYDOWN/KEYUP for <Control> & <Shift> as user is likely still holding them down. ********
// Have to release both left and right, in case user is using keys on either side of keyboard
keys[6].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
keys[6].ki.wVk = VK_RCONTROL;                      // Right <Ctrl>
keys[6].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY;        // Right <Ctrl> key is actually an extended key
                                                   // dwFlags must be set to KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY

keys[7] = keys[6];                                 // Right <Ctrl>
keys[7].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;             // (UP)   OR the KEYUP flag with EXTENDEDKEY

keys[8].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
keys[8].ki.wVk = VK_LCONTROL;                      // Left <Ctrl>

keys[9] = keys[8];                                 // Left <Ctrl>
keys[9].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;              // (UP)   set the KEYUP flag

keys[10].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;                    // 
keys[10].ki.wVk = VK_RSHIFT;                       // Right <Shift>

keys[11] = keys[10];                               // Right <Shift>
keys[11].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;             // (UP)   set the KEYUP flag

keys[12].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;                    // 
keys[12].ki.wVk = VK_LSHIFT;                       // Left <Shift>

keys[13] = keys[12];                               // Left <Shift>
keys[13].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;             // (UP)   set the KEYUP flag

// vvv Send unmodified virtual key next vvv
```

Of course, a Down/Up pair could easily be inserted here for the <Win> key as well.
I hope this helps somebody else through this issue.

Comment: This is all useful info for future readers, but I'm not sure whether it applies to my original problem: wouldn't sending a windows key down/up pair cause the Start menu to display in the same way that I describe in my question? Apologies if I'm missing a part of your answer that avoids this: I'm no longer in a position to easily test this.

Answer (score -1):

There is not a more "straightforward way" for a program to do this without modifying the registry. The ideal solution is to track the keypresses in a table (std::map, Dictionary, etc). The intent of this on MS's part is to prevent viruses/malware from taking control of the keyboard and preventing the user from using important keyboard combos such as WinKey-L and Ctrl-Alt-Delete.

You can, however, remap the keyboard scan codes in the registry if keyboard hooking is not for you. This isn't ideal, since it's hard to reverse (especially if you make a mistake, or your program crashes, or the user uninstalls the application but the registry hack is not reverted). But it does work. Here are some references:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-caps-lock-key-in-windows-vista/

http://www.usnetizen.com/fix_capslock.php

Comment: I don't see how remapping keyboard scan code would help me. I want the Win key not to affect input I simulate with SendInput, but I still want it to work normally otherwise.