# Use SendInput to lock the computer

Tags: c++, windows, sendinput

I want to use SendInput via C++ to lock the computer (`Windows+L`). I have created simple keyDown / keyUp functions in which I use `SendInput` to send a VK. On keyUp, it adds the `flag 0x0002`

I can simulate my tab key, my windows key and now I try to lock my computer with a simulated key stroke. I send the following messages:

```
key down:  0x5B (win key)
key down:  0x4C (L)
key up:    0x4C (L)
key up:    0x5B (win key)
```

My problem: Nothing happens :-(

Does someone know whats the solution?

Comment: Um, why not simply call the [Win32 function designed specifically for locking a system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376875(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: I use this to control a specific application which is controllable via key strokes on a remote computer. I used SendInput for everything in this application, the only function left is to lock the screen after the use. I tried to do all of this via SendInput and I hoped that there is no need to add another mechanism.

Though, if SendInput doesn't work, I'll use the Win32 call you mentioned. But I wonder why it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok. You might find [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906179/low-level-keyboard-hooks-sendinput-with-winkeyl-possible-workstation-lockout) helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you will not be able to do this with `SendInput()` (or `keybd_event()`) because it simply injects the keys into the keyboard input buffer, but special key sequences like `CTRL+ALT+DEL`, `WIN+L`, etc operate at a lower layer that are interpretted by the OS before keys are put in the input buffer.

The correct way to lock the computer is to use the [`LockWorkStation()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376875.aspx) function instead.