# How to trigger a Windows and L key Python-hotkey?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyautogui

I am trying to run this code in Python.

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.hotkey('win', 'l')
```

So that when I run it it will trigger switch user in Windows but all it does is press <kbd>l</kbd> when I need it to press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>

Comment: I think the problem is that Windows handles this key combination especially, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696253/use-sendinput-to-lock-the-computer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As said in my comment, it is most likely that this key combination doesn't work because Windows handles it specially.

If you want to simply lock the workstation, you can use this solution which uses ctypes to call Windows' LockWorkstation-Function:

[Lock windows workstation using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733441/lock-windows-workstation-using-python)

Python code:

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.LockWorkStation()
```

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue for Win+V and instead of using the hotkey function I used:

```
pyautogui.keyDown('winleft')
pyautogui.press('v')
pyautogui.keyUp('winleft')
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.hotkey('winleft', 'l')
```

This is working in my laptop.

Comment: This was what I initially tried but it doesn't work (at least for me). Also tried Zanarks solution, no change when using winleft-l, only ctypes solution by Felix worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.hold('win')
pyautogui.press('l')
```

This is working on my PC if you want to use only pyautogui and not ctypes